# Memory leak in instruments

Tags: iphone

i have in my parser :

```
+(NSArray *)parseMethode:(NSData *)xmlData  {
...
 return [myNSArray autorelease];
}
```

and in an other controller i have done this :

```
@synthesize anOtherNSMutableArray;

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{

NSData *responseData = [self.currentRequest responseData];


self.anOtherNSArray = [MyClassParsers parseMethode:reponseData];
...

}
```

and when i lunch instruments it detect me a leak in the line :

```
self.anOtherNSArray = [MyClassParsers parseMethode:reponseData];
```

is there a leak in my code ??

thanks for your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below

```
self.anOtherNSArray = nil ;
self.anOtherNSArray = [MyClassParsers parseMethode:reponseData];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
 NSData *responseData = [self.currentRequest responseData] autorelease];
```

Comment: What's the reason to do this please ??

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you have defined this kind of property for anOtherNSArray :

```
@property (...,retain) NSArray *anOtherNSArray;
```

the retain property means that using the accessor will retain the value automatically !
using the accessor :

```
self.anOtherNSArray = something;
```

will do the same than not using the accessor but retaining the value :

```
anOtherNSArray = [someting retain];
```

You should either :

- not defining the retain property for anOtherNSArray (use assign instead) if the value doesn't have to be retained here
- not using the accessor (remove the "self.")
- release the instance before setting a new value !

The last option is the easier and safest one (doing "self.anOtherNSArray = nil ;" as stated by Jhaliya will release the instance and set it to nil) !

Reading that may help you understanding a little bit more what are properties : http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/103